# Hide simple product when in configurable

Tags: php, magento

I'm having an issue with the way products are handled in Magento. Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction.

If I have a configurable product called "OMEGA" and the simple products in OMEGA are a,b,c I don't want a,b,c to be displayed on the SEARCH or CATALOG. But if I set to NOT VISIBLE individually and the simple product is out stock, when I try to submit OMEGA with the simple out of stock product I get a "PAGE NOT FOUND" because it's trying to redirect to the simple product that is not visible.

My question is this. How would I not show any simple product if it is attached to a configurable product and have it not display an error message saying page not found if being selected from the configurable product.

Comment: Hi please read [this guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and include relevant code and information.

Comment: I'm sorry there is no code to include. This was more of a question how magento handles simple/configurable products. I was looking for a direction to be pointed in to figure out what I can do. At this time there is no direct code that I have that needs to troubleshoot.